# Conditionally importing npm modules?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, ecmascript-6

My project structure is as follows:

```
- workspace
  - customPackage
    - customIndex.js
  - myProject
    - index.js
  - myProject2
    - index.js
```

In dev, I want to import the package from my local workspace like following:

```
//index.js
import something from '../customePackage/customIndex.js'
```

where as in production I need the import to work from npm modules like the following:

```
//index.js
import something from 'customPackage';
```

The purpose being to be able to use the local changes in the package(without going through the commit cycle). Finally after testing the package can be pushed and used normally via npm package.

How to do this in an efficient way without having to make code changes every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Resolve#alias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias) with Webpack:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        "customPackage": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? 
            "customPackage" :
            path.resolve(__dirname, "../customePackage/customIndex.js")
    }
}
```

Then in your source, you only need to do:

```
import something from 'customPackage';
```

And it will point to the correct package. Obviously you need to set the `NODE_ENV` environment variable, or change that depending on your build environment.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But it is giving me the following error: Module build failed: Error: Parse Error: Line 1: Illegal import declaration.      Probably because I am trying to access a file outside the project directory (which has .babelrc defined) and hence babel loader is not able to load appropriately.

Comment: Yes I am using eslint.  And I do have "ecmaFeatures": {
    "jsx": true,
    "modules": true
  } in my eslint.rc.  Still not working . Plus I am not sure why eslint would stop the babel-loader to load from outside the project directory.

Comment: @SahilSharma Does sound like a Babel issue. You'll need to figure out how to get Webpack to run babel against those files not in your project scope

Comment: Yup , that was second part of my problem.I think I will post a separate question for this. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

if you are already using webpack you can make two different entry points:

```
entry: {
    bundle: './Scripts/index.tsx',
    bundle2: './Scripts/index2.tsx'
},
output: {
    publicPath: "/js/",
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/wwwroot/js/'),
    filename: '[name].js'
},
```

then in `index` you import main module and in `index2` import your test module. So you will have different bundle files `bundle.js` and `bundle2.js`.